# What makes people want to go on shopping sprees?

Tags: venture-towns

Every so often one of my residents glows yellow and goes on a shopping spree.

Is there any way to get them to do this more often? I like earning money!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you need to [add some plants](http://kairospot.net/community/index.php?threads/venture-towns-how-to-play.1704/):

> When a store is very popular, it can trigger a shopping spree, where residents pay up to 4x
>   normal price. Nearby plants boost popularity.

Comment: It's worth noting that Woods and Fruitful Tree are the two exceptions - plants that do *not* increase popularity of adjacent buildings.